# How to model array of key/value pairs

Tags: clickhouse

We are using ClickHouse to store internal performance metrics for webpage loads. Each metric contains an array of key/value pairs for custom load times they care about. We'd like to store these in ClickHouse and be able to query the times like any other time value.

For example, when I get a metric, along with all the standard data I may have data that gives me the load time for a bunch of custom stuff, like this:

```
TimeStamp=1548268715
CustomEvents="a=10,b=20,c=30"
```

In this case, I want to store the values `a=10`, `b=20`, and `c=30` in such a way that:

1. It's still tied to the original data (so I can filter by timestamp, any other field, etc.).
2. I can aggregate and query specific "custom events." For example, I may want to do a histogram on all `a` time values between certain dates.

The challenge is that I don't know in advance which custom events exist. I suppose I could white-list these, but the number of them may become very large, and the cardinality of custom events is very high.

I'd appreciate any thoughts on this. I've got a few ideas, but wouldn't mind any thoughts.

Comment: Did you have a look to Nested structure ?

Answer (score 1):

The standard approach for that in ClickHouse is using Nested structures and select from that using ARRAY JOIN.

Under the hood Nested field in ClickHouse is just a group of arrays of the same length.

Sample:

1. Create the table like that

   ```
   CREATE TABLE performance_metrics
   (
       timestamp DateTime, 
       website String, 
       custom_events Nested (
           metric String,
           value UInt64  -- actually you can have more attributes here, if needed
       )
   )
   ENGINE = MergeTree
   PARTITION BY toMonday(timestamp)
   ORDER BY (website, timestamp);
   ```
2. Put the data, referencing Nested subfields as multiple arrays. Names of those arrays should be prefixed by Nested name, and length should be the same:

   ```
   INSERT INTO performance_metrics (timestamp, website, custom_events.metric, custom_events.value)  VALUES
   ( '2019-02-04 10:00:00', 'google.com',        ['a', 'b', 'c'],[10,20,30]),
   ( '2019-02-04 10:00:01', 'stackoverflow.com', ['b', 'c', 'd'],[22,29,40]),
   ( '2019-02-04 10:00:01', 'google.com',        ['a','d'], [8,42]);
   ```
3. And now you can select from performance_metrics using ARRAY JOIN:

   ```
   SELECT 
       website, 
       custom_events.metric, 
       median(custom_events.value), 
       min(timestamp), 
       max(timestamp)
   FROM performance_metrics 
   ARRAY JOIN custom_events
   GROUP BY 
       website, 
       custom_events.metric
   ORDER BY 
       website ASC, 
       custom_events.metric ASC
   ```

Comment: Is there a way to do this if the data types of the nested structure are unknown?